# key for scrolling up in gnome terminal to check the history of screen?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to check the history of screen of gnome terminal.

Is there a key to scroll up? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the mouse wheel, too.

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> scrolls up by one page at a time and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> scrolls up by one line at a time.